# Exporting with SAP GUI using Python

Tags: python-2.7, sap-gui

I am trying to automate some steps in SAP GUI with Python. I am able to do it for other type of SAP codes except for one where the Excel Export is only chosen through the menu bar "list", then "export", then "spreadsheet". Then a dialog box pops up with the request of the location and name of the file.

The issue I ran into with this case is that the Python code does not bring up steps above like it does with other SAP portion. I use the record Macro of SAP GUI to save it in VBscript and put that into the python code.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[4]/menu[1]").select
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = "directory"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "filename"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 8
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
```

The second line of this code results in nothing. Even though it should activate the menu bar, etc.

Your help in resolving this is appreciated.

Comment: removing Excel tag, since question is not related to anything within Excel.

Comment: `I am able to do it for other type of SAP codes` give your full Python code where it works, give us [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)